# SQL self join sql query

Tags: sql

I am trying to solve below by self join

I have table like this:

```
Employee Name          ReportTo
--------------------------------
Bob                      Peter
Chris                    Tim
ABC                      DEF
Peter                    Null
EFG                      Peter
```

One person have many employee under and there is hierarchy from top level to down. from director to employ. I am trying to create a report to fetch all employees who report to him. Is self join work here or there is any other easy way. I have another condition only top level people can see lower level.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Enter dummy data or a screenshot of your table. Also the desired output you require.

Comment: Employee Name    ReportTo
Bob                Peter
Chris                   Tim
ABC                   DEF
Peter                Null
EFG                  Peter

Comment: Please post what you tried and sample output.... in the actual question. I'm certain this has been answered many times over here , you just have to find it.

Comment: Also tag the database engine you’re using since the answer may depend on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a `self-join` might be used

```
with Employees ( EmployeeName, ReportTo ) as
(
select 'Bob','Peter' union all
select 'Chris','Tim' union all
select 'ABC','DEF' union all
select 'Peter',Null union all
select 'EFG','Peter'
)
select e1.ReportTo, e1.EmployeeName
  from Employees e1
  left join Employees e2 on e2.EmployeeName =e1.ReportTo
 where e1.ReportTo is not null
 order by e1.ReportTo;

ReportTo    EmployeeName
---------   ------------
DEF         ABC
Peter       EFG
Peter       Bob
Tim         Chris
```